# How to find which material is assigned to which purchasing group

Tags: sap-erp

I am trying to find which material part number is assigned to which purchasing group in SAP ERP. If someone could point me to the right tables that would help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchasing group for an article can be found in tables MARA and MARC.

The fields are MAW1-WEKGR and MARC-EKGRP.

I'm using SAP Retail.

Hope it helps.